# Gravity forms and wp_update_post

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, wp-update-post

I am using Gravity Forms to let users create posts.  The user fills out a bunch of information, and a post is created.  The user gets to choose which categories the post is in, but there is one more category that I need to add for every post.  I am trying to use the gform_after_submission hook (http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission) and wp_update_post.  I just want to add one more category to the post.  Here is my code:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_5", "add_category", 10, 2);
function add_category($entry) {
  $post = get_post($entry["post_id"]);
  $post->post_category = array ( 48 );
  wp_update_post($post);
}
```

This does add the appropriate category, so that's good, but it also removes ALL of the other post data, which is bad.

What am I doing wrong?  Can this code be made to work, or should I be taking another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at core, it seems post_category always overwrites:

```
 // Passed post category list overwrites existing category list if not empty.
```

Instead, try something like:

```
//wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append )
wp_set_post_terms( $entry["post_id"], 48, $taxonomy, true )
```

Obviously, replace $taxonomy with the correct name.